# How bcrypt compares passwords with different generated salt?

Tags: javascript, encryption, bcrypt

I am using `bcryptjs` right now and `bcrypt` provides a method to generate salt

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt)
```

and then it uses generated salt to encrypt password

```
bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash)
```

to verify auth it uses compare method

```
bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res)
```

How does `bcrypt` generate same salt to compare passwords? Does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time when `bcrypt` generates salt and hash, he stores salt in generated hash.

**Example**

We have hash - `$2y$14$i5btSOiulHhaPHPbgNUGdObga/GC.AVG/y5HHY1ra7L0C9dpCaw8u`

Format (identifier) - `2y`

Cost parameter - `14`

Salt - `i5btSOiulHhaPHPbgNUGdO`

Hash digest - `bga/GC.AVG/y5HHY1ra7L0C9dpCaw8u`

**P.S.**
You can read about this here - https://github.com/ademarre/binary-mcf

Comment: I have to make a manual compare function. Is that correct to catch same part of hash to make a salt before comparison?